# Huge disk space taken by Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql

My pg_dump takes 2,7 GB but on disk database takes 37GB. I know that indexes can take a lot of space but - can they really take so much ?

below some more information:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('postgres') );
```

pg_size_pretty

---

37 GB
(1 row)

last vacuum was done today:

```
postgres=# SELECT relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
        relname        | last_vacuum |        last_autovacuum
-----------------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 pga_jobclass          |             |
 pga_joblog            |             |
 maindicomtags         |             |
 globalintegers        |             | 2021-03-01 14:17:24.381984+01
 attachedfiles         |             |
 patientrecyclingorder |             | 2021-03-01 14:15:29.491138+01
 pga_jobstep           |             |
 metadata              |             | 2021-02-22 21:54:03.266458+01
 deletedresources      |             |
 resources             |             |
 deletedfiles          |             |
 pga_exception         |             |  
 pga_jobsteplog        |             |
 pga_schedule          |             |
 remainingancestor     |             |
 globalproperties      |             | 2021-03-01 14:16:24.320998+01
 exportedresources     |             |
 pga_jobagent          |             |
 pga_job               |             |
 dicomidentifiers      |             |
 changes               |             |
(21 rows)
```

dead tuples:

```
postgres=# SELECT relname, n_dead_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
        relname        | n_dead_tup
-----------------------+------------
 pga_jobclass          |          0
 pga_joblog            |          0
 maindicomtags         |      13850
 globalintegers        |         92
 attachedfiles         |       3813 
 patientrecyclingorder |        478
 pga_jobstep           |          0
 metadata              |    3908780
 deletedresources      |          0
 resources             |       2562
 deletedfiles          |          0
 pga_exception         |          0
 pga_jobsteplog        |          0
 pga_schedule          |          0
 remainingancestor     |          0
 globalproperties      |         18
 exportedresources     |          0
 pga_jobagent          |          1
 pga_job               |          0
 dicomidentifiers      |       2972 
 changes               |       3392
(21 rows)
```

and indexes:

```
postgres=# SELECT
postgres-#     tablename,
postgres-#     indexname,
postgres-#     indexdef
postgres-# FROM
postgres-#     pg_indexes
postgres-# WHERE
postgres-#     schemaname = 'public'
postgres-# ORDER BY
postgres-#     tablename,
postgres-#     indexname;
       tablename       |          indexname           |                                                  indexdef
-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
 attachedfiles         | attachedfiles_pkey           | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX attachedfiles_pkey ON public.attachedfiles USING btree (id, filetype)
 changes               | changes_pkey                 | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX changes_pkey ON public.changes USING btree (seq)
 changes               | changesindex                 | CREATE INDEX changesindex ON public.changes USING btree (internalid)
 dicomidentifiers      | dicomidentifiers_pkey        | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dicomidentifiers_pkey ON public.dicomidentifiers USING btree (id, taggroup, tagelement)    
 dicomidentifiers      | dicomidentifiersindex1       | CREATE INDEX dicomidentifiersindex1 ON public.dicomidentifiers USING btree (id)
 dicomidentifiers      | dicomidentifiersindex2       | CREATE INDEX dicomidentifiersindex2 ON public.dicomidentifiers USING btree (taggroup, tagelement) 
 dicomidentifiers      | dicomidentifiersindexvalues  | CREATE INDEX dicomidentifiersindexvalues ON public.dicomidentifiers USING btree (value)
 dicomidentifiers      | dicomidentifiersindexvalues2 | CREATE INDEX dicomidentifiersindexvalues2 ON public.dicomidentifiers USING gin (value gin_trgm_ops)
 exportedresources     | exportedresources_pkey       | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX exportedresources_pkey ON public.exportedresources USING btree (seq)
 globalintegers        | globalintegers_pkey          | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX globalintegers_pkey ON public.globalintegers USING btree (key)
 globalproperties      | globalproperties_pkey        | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX globalproperties_pkey ON public.globalproperties USING btree (property)
 maindicomtags         | maindicomtags_pkey           | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX maindicomtags_pkey ON public.maindicomtags USING btree (id, taggroup, tagelement)
 maindicomtags         | maindicomtagsindex           | CREATE INDEX maindicomtagsindex ON public.maindicomtags USING btree (id)
 metadata              | metadata_pkey                | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX metadata_pkey ON public.metadata USING btree (id, type)
 patientrecyclingorder | patientrecyclingindex        | CREATE INDEX patientrecyclingindex ON public.patientrecyclingorder USING btree (patientid)
 patientrecyclingorder | patientrecyclingorder_pkey   | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX patientrecyclingorder_pkey ON public.patientrecyclingorder USING btree (seq)
 resources             | childrenindex                | CREATE INDEX childrenindex ON public.resources USING btree (parentid)
 resources             | publicindex                  | CREATE INDEX publicindex ON public.resources USING btree (publicid)
 resources             | resources_pkey               | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX resources_pkey ON public.resources USING btree (internalid)
 resources             | resourcetypeindex            | CREATE INDEX resourcetypeindex ON public.resources USING btree (resourcetype) 
(20 rows)
```

How its possible ? I am runing out of ideas.
Is it maybe possible to calculate size of indexes itself ?

Greetings
Kris

Comment: Don't forget that the auto vacuum will not release the space to the OS, it will only let PG use this space again. A full vacuum will release the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the query presented in a Postgres Weekly [tip](https://postgresweekly.com/issues/294)

```
SELECT
  schemaname as schema_name,
  relname AS table_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) AS total,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) AS internal,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) AS external,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(relid)) AS indexes
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
--WHERE schemaname = 'myshema' **********
--ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC; -- total size
--ORDER BY (pg_table_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) DESC; --external size
ORDER BY schemaname, relname; --name
```